# Polygon vertices to lat/lon in python using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I am trying to get the points for all vertices of my multipolygons using `psychopg2`  The following code successfully executes...

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText(geom)) from dry_overlay""")


rows = cur.fetchall()
print "\nShow me the databases:\n"
for row in rows:
    print "   ", row[0]
```

but it produces an output that looks like this:

```
("{1,1,1}",0101000000F3071C3FF0E04241C729FC3E2C735A41)
("{1,1,2}",01010000009C700A93FFDF4241DA0BBD6283725A41)
("{1,1,3}",01010000001BC9122701E04241C2D848ED2C735A41)
("{1,1,4}",0101000000325487970FE04241FF279CE92C735A41)
("{1,1,5}",0101000000B188A3F06FE042414A73142B2C735A41)
("{1,1,6}",0101000000F3071C3FF0E04241C729FC3E2C735A41)
("{1,1,1}",010100000019D5589E634D4341B7E69817C2875A41)
("{1,1,2}",010100000042AEF52E2E4D43418CD52A53C1875A41)
("{1,1,3}",01010000006D4CBA551F4D43411EBEF35CC1875A41)
("{1,1,4}",0101000000D92F2F601F4D43413AD9BADAB9875A41)
("{1,1,5}",0101000000AF1860920F4D43410E00CDDBB9875A41)
```

I understand that the second element is WKT but how would one go about converting that into a lat/long coordinates? I thought `ST_AsText()` would perform this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ST_AsText is the function you need, but in another place:

```
SELECT ST_Astext((ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom) from dry_overlay;
```

Even better use ST_X and ST_Y, so you don't have to parse the text:

```
SELECT ST_x(geom), ST_y(geom) FROM (
    SELECT (St_DumpPoints(geom)).geom from dry_overlay
  ) as foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `wkb` module from the excellent `shapely` package to load and manipulate the geometry:

```
from shapely import geometry, wkb

test_geom = geometry.Point(0, 0)
test_wkb_hex = wkb.dumps(test_geom, hex=True)

print(test_wkb_hex) # prints: '010100000000000000000000000000000000000000'

my_geom = wkb.loads(test_wkb_hex, hex=True)

print(my_geom) # prints: POINT (0 0)
```

In your case, simply use the `wkb.loads(record_geom, hex=True)` method on your response.

You can then use `shapely`'s `geometry` module to extract your vertices or do any other number of tasks.

For example, `my_geom.coords.xy` will return `x`, `y` arrays of your coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty fast on the server.

Answer (score 0):

[PPyGIS](http://www.fabianowski.eu/projects/ppygis/) function `ppygis.Geometry.read_ewkb(...)` could help you.